How can we tell Twilio to leave a TaskRouter queue and go back to Studio?
I am using a Twilio TaskRouter so that I can play a special audio file while Twilio rings a SIP endpoint. When the callee doesn't answer the phone after 30 seconds, how do I tell TaskRouter to leave the queue?
I know I can use the waitUrl and the audio file will loop and at the start of each loop I can detect the timeout and give some TwiML to do other things, but I want a specific timeout that doesn't match the time it takes to play through the audio file.
I have a TwiML redirect in place, so if the <Enqueue> verb ever finishes, it should go back to the Studio Flow to continue the call progression, but...
How do I tell TaskRouter to finish the <Enqueue> verb? Right now I have a timeout on the workflow assignment and I can pick up on the timed-out call via the callback script, but I can't redirect the call with TwiML because it's not a call in progress and I can't cancel nor complete the task nor the workflow because neither one is in a state that is appropriate.
I saw someone reference a <Leave > tag in another post, but I cannot find it in the docs anywhere. I can't get my poor callers out of this queue and back to the Studio Flow!
What am I missing?

I've noticed that if I put a <Leave /> command in the Assignment URL, I can break out of the task router. So I created a second task queue with an agent so that when the Assignment URL is called the second time during the call (when it matches the second task queue), it will receive the TwiML to leave the task router.
However, I get multiple error 40122s with HTTP code 400 telling me that the "The redirect instruction encountered an error when redirecting a call via the API. Code: 21220 - Call is not in-progress. Cannot redirect." What on God's green earth am I missing, here?
